# How to use statusChanged in WebView ( QtQuick 2.0 and QtWebKit 3)?

Tags: c++, qml, qtwebkit, qt-quick

In QtQuick 1.0 and QtWebKit 1.0 i could do onLoadFinished to execute function after page was ready. How to do it in versions 2 and 3 respectively?

There is a statusChanged in docuements. Id don't understand how to use it.

Previously i  had:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtWebKit 3.0

WebView {
    width: 700
    height: 800

    url:"http://www.yahoo.com"
    settings.developerExtrasEnabled : true


    id: webView
    objectName: "myWebView"




    onLoadFinished: evaluateJavaScript("window.setTimeout('window.location.reload()',5000);")

}
```

but it shows error:
Cannot assign to non-existent property "onLoadFinished"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the `onLoadingChanged` signal and loadRequest object to check the exact status:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwebkit/qml-qtwebkit3-webview.html#onLoadingChanged-signal

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtWebKit 3.0

WebView {
    width: 700
    height: 800

    url:"http://google.com"

    id: webView
    objectName: "myWebView"

    onLoadingChanged: {
        console.log("onLoadingChanged: status=" + loadRequest.status);
        if (loadRequest.status == WebView.LoadStartedStatus) 
            console.log("Loading started...");
        if (loadRequest.status == WebView.LoadFailedStatus) {
           console.log("Load failed! Error code: " + loadRequest.errorCode);
           if (loadRequest.errorCode === NetworkReply.OperationCanceledError)
               console.log("Load cancelled by user");
        } 
        if (loadRequest.status == WebView.LoadSucceededStatus) 
            console.log("Page loaded!");
    }

}
```

The `onLoadingChanged` signal occurs when any page load begins, ends, or fails. Various read-only parameters are available on the loadRequest:

- url: the location of the resource that is loading.
- status: Reflects one of three load states: LoadStartedStatus, LoadSucceededStatus, or LoadFailedStatus. See WebView::LoadStatus.
- errorString: description of load error.
- errorCode: HTTP error code.
- errorDomain: high-level error types, one of NetworkErrorDomain, HttpErrorDomain, InternalErrorDomain, DownloadErrorDomain, or NoErrorDomain. See WebView::ErrorDomain.